# TSQL: Grouping LARGE amounts of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a project I'm working on that requires that I group records that look like below and I need some help...

Here's the current structure:

Table: **Forms**

```
FormID     FormName     FormType     GroupID   <<< New column
----------------------------------------------
1          Form1        1
2          Form1        1
3          Form2        2
4          Form2        2
5          Form2        2
```

Table: **Fields**

```
FieldID     FormID     FieldLabel     IsRequired    OtherField...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1          Label1         1            x
2           1          Label2         0            y
3           1          Label3         0            z
4           2          Label1         1            x
5           2          Label2         0            y
6           2          Label3         0            z
7           3          Label1         1            x
8           3          Label2         0            y
9           3          Label3         0            z   
10          4          Label1         1            x
11          4          Label2         0            y
12          4          Label3         0            z
13          5          Label1         1            a
14          5          Label2         0            b
15          5          Label3         0            c
```

So what I need to do is group the Forms and Fields together and see if they are exactly alike - even the DATA - which is where I'm stumped. For example Forms 1 & 2 would be grouped together because FormName and FormType match and in the fields table the FieldLabel, IsRequired and "OtherField" all match.

However even though Forms 3, 4 & 5 all match on the forms table, only Forms 3 & 4 would end up in the same group because the data (OtherFields) in the Fields table isn't the same on those columns.

Desired results for Forms table (Specifically, the "GroupID" column):

```
FormID     FormName     FormType     GroupID 
----------------------------------------------
1          Form1        1             1
2          Form1        1             1
3          Form1        2             2
4          Form2        2             2
5          Form2        2             3
```

How can this be done?  I don't mind using cursors, etc since this is a one-time deal to populate the new "GroupID" column.

Thanks guys!

***EDIT***
Here's the fiddle created by Andrew: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ec6f/6

Comment: In the table 'Forms' the 'FormName' of the FormID = 5 and FormName = Form2, the name does't match with the result in last row 'FormID' = 5 and 'FormName' = Form5, it's an error?

Comment: you mean the first "Forms" table doesn't match my "Desired Results" - yea that is an error - i'll fix for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you have in mind:

```
;with types as (
select
distinct formtype,
row_number()over (order by formtype) as GroupID
from 
(select distinct formtype from forms) t1)


select
f.formid,
f.formname,
f.formtype,
types.GroupID
from
forms f
inner join types
on f.formtype = types.formtype
```

The CTE generates the group id for form type, and then you just join that to your forms table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f671/20)

Comment: Oh, sweet, there's a "SQL Fiddle" too! nice!  This is ALMOST what I need - it's not taking the fields into account.  The number of fields between forms need to match as well as specific columns data (ie: FieldLabel, IsRequired, OtherFields, etc) - Thanks Andrew.

Comment: Dang, yeah.  After re-reading, not entirely sure I understand your requirements with the fields table.

Comment: Basically it's the same as what you did with forms, but some of the columns that need to match are in the Fields table too.  I wonder if I just add an INNER JOIN to the cte if that would do it.

Comment: Would formid 4 end up in the same groupid as formid 1?

Comment: no because the FormName is different.  I updated your fiddle so that you didn't have to type all those inserts for the fields table =)